# Django: can't retrieve variable from my view after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

After an AJAX Post request, I'm trying to retrieve from my view some list values contained in a variable. The idea is to use these values to populate a dropdown. But my variable seems empty. I thought that it was because I initially used a 'return render()', but even with a 'return HttpResponse()' it doesn't work.

This is my views.py:

```
def MyView3(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:

        myVariable = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        print(myVariable)

        return HttpResponse(myVariable)
    else:
        return render(request,'home3.html')
```

This is my html code:

```
<form class="wrapper" action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} 

  <select name="myVal" class="toChange">
    <option val="1">1</option>  
    <option val="2">2</option>   
  </select>

  <select id="dep" name="dep">
    {% for item in myVariable %}
      <option val="{{ item }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
      {% endfor %}
  </select>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownChange () {
      var selectedValue = $(".toChange option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data: {'myVal': selectedValue},
              }); 
      var mylist = '{{myVariable}}';
      alert(mylist);
    }
    $(".toChange").change(dropdownChange);
  </script>

</form>
```

The idea here is to triger the AJAX call when I select a new value in my 'myVal' dropdown. The call works since the view is correctly activated, as 'print(myVariable)' shows the expected result in the console. Moreover, my alert pop-up is displayed. Yet, it is empty. I would need it to show the values contained in 'myVariable', so '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]'. I assume it should be something simple, but I couldn't figure out what. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `URL` and the success callback in the `Ajax` call. You could get the response in the success Callback.

You are getting null in alert because the `$.ajax` is an async function and alert will appear before the `ajax` call can complete.

Try the below example.

**Example:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownChange () {
      var selectedValue = $(".toChange option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
              url: "<add the url>"
              type: 'POST',
              data: {'myVal': selectedValue},
              success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
              }
        });       
    }
    $(".toChange").change(dropdownChange);
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure, what url should I add here? The same that is used by my view (for example: myApp/templates/)?

Comment: Url of of the api where the `def MyView3(request):` method is defined.

Comment: Thank you it seems to work. Nevertheless, I have one question. The alert(res) code returns '12345', so it concatenates my result. How can we return a list instead?

Comment: Alert can only show string value, if you want to print the strings then you have to create your own custom popup.

Comment: You could create the popup box something like this . https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp